# Proving that $G/H$ is Hausdorff

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a normal subgroup. I want to show that $G/H$ is a topological group. I have managed to prove that $m:G/H\times G/H\to G/H, \bar a \bar b\to \bar{ab}$ and $i:G/H\to G/H: \bar a\to \bar {a^{-1}}$ is continuous, but I cannot figure out how to prove that $G/H$ is Hausdorff. I know that proving that $H$ is closed would solve the problem, but how can I prove it? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is normal in $\mathbb{R}$ but not closed.

Comment: I think that you may be a victim of conflicting conventions. Some people require "Hausdorff" as part of the definition of topological group, while others do not. The fact that any quotient of a topological group is a topological group with the quotient topology is true only if "topological group" doesn't include Hausdorffness. Generally the quotient is Hausdorff iff $H$ is closed, so the most you can say is that "the quotient of $G$ by the closure of $H$ is a Hausdorff topological group".

Answer (score 1):

Proving via function composition is much easier.

**Theorem 1.** Let $(S, \cdot)$ be a group and $\tau_S$ be a topology on $S$. Then $(S,\cdot,\tau)$ is a topological group iff the function

\begin{aligned}
f \ \colon \ S \times S & \longrightarrow S\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto xy^{-1},
\end{aligned}

is continuous.

Proof: **Exercise**. ([Dikran](https://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Edikran.dikranjan/ITG.pdf) presents this as a definition but it is possible to prove it through function composition. One tip is to use translation homeomorphisms together with the operation and group inversion.)

Let $(G, \cdot, \tau_G)$ be a topologial group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the quotient $\dfrac{G}{H}$ endowed by the quotient topology induced by $G$.

We have that:

1. The function

\begin{aligned}
f \ \colon \ G \times G & \longrightarrow G\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto xy^{-1}
\end{aligned}

is continuous, because $(G, \cdot, \tau_G)$ is a topological group.

2. The function

\begin{aligned}
q \ \colon G & \longrightarrow  \dfrac{G}{H}\\
g &\longmapsto gH
\end{aligned}

is continuous by definition. **(Note that a set $U \subset \dfrac{G}{H}$ is open iff $q^{-1}(U) \in \tau_G$)**.

We can easily show that the function

\begin{aligned}
q \ \colon G \times G & \longrightarrow  \dfrac{G}{H} \times  \dfrac{G}{H}  \\
(x,y) &\longmapsto (xH, yH)
\end{aligned}

is continuous with respect to product topolgy. **We then have all the tools to prove this statement**. Then, consider the function:

\begin{aligned}
F \ \colon \dfrac{G}{H} \times \dfrac{G}{H} & \longrightarrow  \dfrac{G}{H} \\
(xH,yH) &\longmapsto xy^{-1}H.
\end{aligned}

Note that that the diagram

$\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ [image: composition]

commutes. Therefore

$$q \circ f = F \circ (q \times q).$$

The first member of this equality is a continuous application in $(x, y)$. We then have that $F \circ (q \times q)$ must be continuous in $(x, y)$. Since the map $q \times q$ is continuous in $(x, y)$, we have that $F$ is continuous in $(xH, yH) = (q \times q)(x, y).$ By the **Theorem 1**, whe have that $\bigg(\dfrac{G}{H}, \cdot, \tau_{\frac{G}{H}}\bigg)$ is a topological group.